# Where was Ormalonsok Hungary?

Tags: historical-gazetteer, hungary

In an effort to locate my grandfather's Hungarian birth certificate (born in 1924) I need to narrow down his place of residence/birth prior to him immigrating abroad. On the ships manifest it shows the town as Ormalonsok Hungary but this town can't be found on Google? Any idea how to find out where it could have been?

I have attached a copy of the passenger manifest. Our ancestors were listed in lines 10-15.

[image: Ship Manifest to Canada]

Comment: Welcome to GFH.SE. Very few places in Hungary start with Orm, according to my Hungary gazetteer, and none come close to Ormalonsok. Also checked at radixindex.com. Please edit to give us the passenger's name and ship details or a link to the record, so we can try for a different transcription of the place name. (You may be too new to add an image).

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! Please let us know if you find any other records such as naturalization papers, a death cerfiticate, etc. The FamilySearch Research Wiki's guide on tracing immigrant ancestors may be useful. https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/United_States_Emigration_and_Immigration

You can use the edit link under your question at any time to add any other information you find. You may need to consult records from other family members, associates, or neighbors who also came from Hungary.

Comment: Hi all and thanks for your input. I've attached the ship's manifest.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! Please iclude the citation details for your passenger list in the question.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's trying to be Ómalomsok, which was in Győr county, a few miles from that little corner where Sopron, Vas, Veszprém, and Győr counties met. The village was combined with Újmalomsok in 1950 to make Malomsok, and it's now in Veszprém county.

The 1913 gazetteer says the civil registry office was in Újmalomsok; FamilySearch has those records available up to 1906 (https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/829119).

Dvorzsák's gazetteer (https://kt.lib.pte.hu/cgi-bin/kt.cgi?konyvtar/kt03110501/0_0_1_pg_238.html) indicates that the population was nearly all Roman Catholic, and they were recorded in Marczaltő (in Veszprém county: https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/302450).

Answer (score 1):

Not a definitive answer ...

Since the record is mosty typed: there is little handwriting to interpret. The placename is spelled Ormalonsok on the image, which can't be found with that spelling.
Options from the columns on the right-hand page:

- Passports for the family were issued in Veszprém. Archives there might have records of those documents. Visually check maps in that region of Hungary for villages with some simularity to Ormalonsok.
- Departure contact was mother living in Budapest. Perhaps Ormalonsok is actually a neighbourhood or a street name.

Answer (score 0):

In searching for my own family history, I have two different spellings for the town/village that my great grandparents came from. Given that the person writing the information down was trying to decipher what these people were saying, the spelling was of course wrong.The spelling I received was O'Malomsok, and O'Malowsaj.I believe
user avatar
JPmiaou is absolutely correct. As I believe my family also came from there